# Bounds on a set of points in the plane whose subsets all have a line of symmetry

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have a set $S$ of points in the plane, not all colinear, with the property that any nonempty subset of $S$ has a line of symmetry. What is the maximum size of $S$?

I suspect that the unique maximal configuration is a regular pentagon along with its center:

[image]

However, I haven't had much luck proving this, and my attempts at providing an upper bound didn't seem to get below numbers around $20$ before devolving into horrible casework and intersection-counting.

Any thoughts on proofs, references, or larger sets $S$ with this property? If there are well-known generalizations, e.g. to 3-space, I'd be curious about that too.

Comment: The empty set of points in the plane has a line of symmetry, no need to exclude that case :)